# Where can I find options used for swap devices?

Tags: linux, swap

When adding swap space for paging there are options other than priority (`pri=`).
For example `discard`.

However I could not find where to read back those options.
`/proc/swaps` just has a `priority` column, and `/proc/mounts` does not list swap.
`swapon -s` just seems to output the same information as `/proc/swaps` does.

So where can I get those options (without having to write a C program)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way of retrieving the swap flags which don’t feature in `/proc/swaps`, even by writing a C program. The only way to find out what the flags are, would be to modify the kernel.

To check this, look for users of [`swap_info_struct.flags`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.13/source/include/linux/swap.h#L241). The implementation of `/proc/swaps` is in [`mm/swapfile.c`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8.13/source/mm/swapfile.c#L2787).

Comment: I suspected such an answer, thus filing an enhancement request for the Linux kernel: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=209563